# <DIV> inside link (<a href="">) tag

Tags: css, html

I want to make a div click-able and but inside this `<div>` i have another `<div>` which also should be click-able or linked.

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="box">
       <div class="plus"><img src="aaa.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.plus{
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Can i make both `<div>`s to link and for different links?

and Is this proper way use div inside `a href` ?

Comment: Is it even possible to make links of block elements?

Comment: @Wai: I presume you are asking whether an <a> can be displayed like a block? If so, yes. <a href="#" style="display: block;">blah</a> is perfectly valid, and in very common use.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I was wondering if it's possible to nest a block element in a link tag. (not sure if I wrote it correctly, English is not my native language)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**No,** the link assigned to the containing `<a>` will be assigned to every elements inside it.

And, this is not the proper way. You can make a `<a>` behave like a `<div>`.

An Example <sup>*[[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/VCMB5/)*</sup>

CSS

```
a.divlink { 
     display:block;
     width:500px;
     height:500px; 
     float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <a class="divlink" href="yourlink.html">
         The text or elements inside the elements
    </a>
    <a class="divlink" href="yourlink2.html">
         Another text or element
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i am also want link text or element to another link!

Comment: @kc rajput, it is not possible inside one `<a>` look at the example again for a possible example

Answer (score 27):

[As of HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-a-element.html) it is OK to wrap `<a>` elements around a `<div>` (or any other block elements):

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

Just have to make sure you don't put an `<a>` within your `<a>` ( or a `<button>`).

Comment: Could u plz provide a reference?

Comment: From the W3 HTML 5 -- "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."  So really the only thing you don't want to put inside a link is other clickable elements for obvious reasons.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-a-element.html

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case of [divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis) - you don't need a div to be clickable, just give the `<a>` tag a class. Then edit the CSS of the class to display:block, and define a height and width like a lot of other answers have mentioned.

The `<a>` tag works perfectly well on its own, so you don't need an extra level of mark-up on the page.

Comment: the only smart guy on this page

Answer (score 2):

Nesting of 'a' will not be possible. 
However if you badly want to keep the structure and still make it work like the way you want,
then override the anchor tag click in javascript /jquery .

so you can have 2 event listeners for the two and control them accordingly.

Comment: is this possible to change in css like z-index?

Comment: No. This is a structural problem, not a styling problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it the other way round.
Define your `Div`s and have your `a href` within each `Div`, pointing to different links

Comment: yes these both divs have differents links.

Answer (score 0):

I would just format two different a-tags with `a { display: block; height: 15px; width: 40px; }` . This way you don't even need the div-tags...