# Links don't work after css animation

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm making a portfolio for my 8th grade exit interview with HTML, Javacript, and CSS. For some reason, after my CSS animation plays, my anchor tags no longer work.

You can see a demo [here](http://thomaswd.com/Portfolio2/).

Here is my code for one of the links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="one()"><div class=img id="img1"> </div></a>
```

And my css:

```
@keyframes secondwindow
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes secondwindow
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes secondwindow
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes secondwindow
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
```

Comment: I think you problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092610/div-inside-link-a-href-tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `div`s are floated but the containing `a` isn't, so the `a`s end up with effectively no dimensions.  A simple solution would just be to also float the `a`s.

Comment: so if I do <a style="float:left">

Comment: Yes, or in the CSS.  You may want to re-work it so the `a`s dictate the layout, but this is a simple fix to get you where you need to go.

Comment: It should fix the containment issue.  `#section1` is also layered on top of the entire page so that will block actually clicking the links.  Remove the `z-index` on that element.  I'm not sure what `one` is supposed to do, but swapping that for test handlers works fine.